# mix two two-dimensional arrays into 1 two-dimensional array

Tags: c#, arrays

i am trying the results which stored int previous arrays (1 and 2) in a new array 3 can show each result from array 1 with with each array 2, when i show the results from each one separately they are okay but when i try to mix them in array 3 i get the correct answers for the first value in array 1 with all values in array 2 then a lot of zeros appears.

here is the code for the array 3

```
for (int i = 0; i < result1.GetLength(0); i++)
          {
               for (int j = 0; j < result1.GetLength(1); j++)
               {
                   for (int k = 0; k < result2.GetLength(0); k++)
                    {
                      for (int m = 0; m < result2.GetLength(1); m++)
                       {

                            result3[i, j] = result1[i, j] + "," + result2[k, m];
                            Console.WriteLine(result3[i, j]);

                            counter++;
                        }
                    }

                }

            }
```

and here is the whole code

```
double[,] Cranelocations = { { -12.3256, 0.5344 }, { -12.3256, -0.4656 }, { -12.3256, -1.4656 }, { -12.3256, -2.4656 } };

double[,] Picklocation = { { -0.3256, -3.4656 }, { 0.6744, -3.4656 }, { 1.6744, -3.4656 }, { 2.6744, -3.4656 }, { 3.6744, -3.4656 }, { 4.6744, -3.4656 }, { 5.6744, -3.4656 } };

double[,] Setlocation = { { 20.62, 5.03 }, { 24.28, 5.03 }, { 28.40, 5.03 }, { 32.11, 5.03 }, { 35.99, 5.26 }, { 40.18, 5.26 } };

double[] Weights = { 11.7865, 14.7335, 15.1015, 10.7465 };

double[,] result1 = new double[Weights.Length * Cranelocations.GetLength(0), Picklocation.GetLength(0)];

double[,] result2 = new double[Weights.Length * Cranelocations.GetLength(0), Setlocation.GetLength(0)];

object[,] result3 = new object[result1.GetLength(0) * result1.GetLength(1), result2.GetLength(0) * result2.GetLength(1)];

            int counter = 0;

            for (int m = 0; m < Weights.Length; m++)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < Cranelocations.GetLength(0); i++)
                {
                    for (int j = 0; j < Picklocation.GetLength(0); j++)
                    {


                        double x = Cranelocations[i, 0] - Picklocation[j, 0];
                        double y = Cranelocations[i, 1] - Picklocation[j, 1];

                        result1[i, j] = Weights[m] * (Math.Sqrt(Math.Pow(x, 2) + Math.Pow(y, 2)));


                    }


                }
            }

            Console.WriteLine("-----------------------------------------------------------------");

            for (int m = 0; m < Weights.Length; m++)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < Cranelocations.GetLength(0); i++)
                {
                    for (int j = 0; j < Setlocation.GetLength(0); j++)
                    {


                        double x = Cranelocations[i, 0] - Setlocation[j, 0];
                        double y = Cranelocations[i, 1] - Setlocation[j, 1];

                        result2[i, j] = Weights[m] * (Math.Sqrt(Math.Pow(x, 2) + Math.Pow(y, 2)));


                    }

                }
            }


            for (int i = 0; i < result1.GetLength(0); i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < result1.GetLength(1); j++)
                {
                    for (int k = 0; k < result2.GetLength(0); k++)
                    {
                        for (int m = 0; m < result2.GetLength(1); m++)
                        {

                            result3[i, j] = result1[i, j] + "," + result2[k, m];
                            Console.WriteLine(result3[i, j]);

                            counter++;

                        }
                    }

                }

            }

}
```

Comment: Try putting your code into https://dotnetfiddle.net/ so we can see the result and why its not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For each `m` you reset `i` to 0 and start writing at the beginning of your array again.

You need to keep moving the index forward when you increment `m`.

The same is when you are combining the two indexes. When you are combining two iterations to get an index you generally multiply the first by the length of the second, then add them together.

```
for (int m = 0; m < Weights.Length; m++)
{
    int offset = m * Cranelocations.GetLength(0);

    for (int i = 0; i < Cranelocations.GetLength(0); i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < Picklocation.GetLength(0); j++)
        {
            double x = Cranelocations[i, 0] - Picklocation[j, 0];
            double y = Cranelocations[i, 1] - Picklocation[j, 1];

            result1[i + offset, j] = Weights[m] * (Math.Sqrt(Math.Pow(x, 2) + Math.Pow(y, 2)));
        }
    }
}

Console.WriteLine("-----------------------------------------------------------------");

for (int m = 0; m < Weights.Length; m++)
{
    int offset = m * Cranelocations.GetLength(0);

    for (int i = 0; i < Cranelocations.GetLength(0); i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < Setlocation.GetLength(0); j++)
        {
            double x = Cranelocations[i, 0] - Setlocation[j, 0];
            double y = Cranelocations[i, 1] - Setlocation[j, 1];

            result2[i + offset, j] = Weights[m] * (Math.Sqrt(Math.Pow(x, 2) + Math.Pow(y, 2)));
        }
    }
}

for (int i = 0; i < result1.GetLength(0); i++)
{
    int iOffset = i * result1.GetLength(1);

    for (int j = 0; j < result1.GetLength(1); j++)
    {
        for (int k = 0; k < result2.GetLength(0); k++)
        {
            int kOffset = k * result2.GetLength(1);

            for (int m = 0; m < result2.GetLength(1); m++)
            {
                result3[iOffset + j, kOffset + m] = result1[i, j] + "," + result2[k, m];
                Console.WriteLine(result3[iOffset + j, kOffset + m]);

                counter++;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: my intention to use result 3 is to put each result from Array result 1 with each result from Array result 2 and show them like this (    ,     ).
and thanks so much for replying i will try what you have posted now.

Comment: Thanks so much for help but if i may Jerry i wanna ask you again if you can explain to me in more details how did you find the problem and the code exactly ? :)

Comment: It worked without the your edit in the 4 loops of result 3 ? isn't that weird ? :D

Comment: When you said the end of your arrays were empty I copied your code in to a console app, put a break point after the `result1` was built and noticed it also was empty at the end of the array. Then it came to me what the problem was.

Comment: It would definitely work before the edit but the console would keep repeating `result[i, j]` for every iteration of k & m.

Comment: okay i have another question because as i told you i am trying to put all these values in result 3 as i mentioned before like this ( x  ,  y  ) then i have to get the max value of each point of this ( x , y ) for the whole points then get the min value of the maximum values  , i managed to get the maximum values but when i try to get the minimum of them it turns shows zero.

Comment: I suggest that you start a new question and post the code that you are using to do that. Try to explain very clearly what you are trying to accomplish. It might be better suited for https://codereview.stackexchange.com/